# plain text can be enctypted like password in vi editor?

Tags: 14.04, password, encryption, text-editor, vi

Can anyone tell me, How to plain text can be enctypted like password (********) in vi editor or using vi editor or any other method ?

Comment: just encrypt some text in file not the whole file

Comment: No method I know of, except of course using copy & paste & gpg manually...

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you really want to achieve

- If you want to encrypt the whole file with **vim**, you can simply run `vim -x myfile.txt` and vim will ask you for a passphrase to encrypt your file. On next opening of the file, you don't even need to use `-x` as vim will find out that it is encrypted and will ask you for the passphrase.
- If you want to encrypt only a string in a file with **vim**, you can run an external command, or you use [this help](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Encryption) from the Vim Wikia.
- If you want to replace all characters of a word with *, you can use `vegr*` with the cursor on the first character of a word.